# iverilog unable to bind parameter

Tags: fpga, verilog, hdl

When using iverilog to compile a script I get the following error:

```
./alu.v:14: error: Unable to bind parameter 'sel' in `alu_tb.x1'
./alu.v:14: error: Cannot evaluate genvar case expression: sel
2 error(s) during elaboration.
```

The problem code is as follows:

```
module alu(
a,
b,
sel,
out
);

input[7:0] a, b;
input[2:0] sel;
wire a,  b, sel;
output[7:0] out;
reg out;

case(sel)
    3'b000: assign out = a + b;
    3'b001: assign out = a - b;
    3'b010: assign out = a * b;
    3'b011: assign out = a / b;
    3'b100: assign out = a & b;
    3'b101: assign out = a | b;
    3'b110: assign out = a ^ b;
    3'b111: assign out = ~a;
endcase

endmodule
```

Is anyone able to see what the problem is here, i'm rather new to verilog. If you see anything that can be done better then I would appreciate the guidance.

Comment: You need to show us `alu_tb`

Comment: Here is alu_tb.v


`include "alu.v"

module alu_tb();

reg[7:0] a, b, out;
reg[2:0] sel;

initial begin
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    out = 0;
    sel = 0;

end

alu x1(a, b, sel, out);

endmodule

Answer (score 1):

You want a procedural case, which must be defined inside inside an procedural block. In your case you want it in an combinaional block which should be `always @*` or the synonymous `always @(*)` When following modern Verilog coding guidelines.  Also, in Verilog a `reg` cannot be assigned by an `assign` statement (SystemVerilog allows it).

```
always @* begin
  case(sel)
    3'b000: out = a + b;
    3'b001: out = a - b;
    3'b010: out = a * b;
    3'b011: out = a / b;
    3'b100: out = a & b;
    3'b101: out = a | b;
    3'b110: out = a ^ b;
    3'b111: out = ~a;
  endcase
end
```

When a `case` is declared outside of the `always` block is a generate case which is evaluated only during elaboration. It's input can only be a `parameter`, a `genvar`, or a literal constant. This is a useful feature for advance users but is a common pitfall for people just learning the language.

Other note. Your module header is written in the non-ANSI style which was required in IEEE1364-1995. Since IEEE1364-2001, the ANSI style header preferred because it is less typing, easier to read, and thereby less error prone when the port list gets long.

ANSI (IEEE1364-2001 and above):

```
module alu(
  input [7:0] a, b,
  input [2:0] sel,
  output reg [7:0] out
);
```

non-ANSI (required for IEEE1364-1995; backward compatible for all other versions):

```
module alu(
  a,
  b,
  sel,
  out
);

input  [7:0] a, b;
input  [2:0] sel;
output [7:0] out;
reg    [7:0] out;
```

Answer (score 0):

The **case** statement is a sequential statement, not a concurrent statement, so it needs to be inside an **always** block

If you plan to synthesize this code then you should add a **default** clause to the **case** statement. You may also have trouble synthesizing the multiplication and division operators, depending on your target.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now when i put the block into an "always @(*) begin .. end" block it says: "internal warning: NetCAssign::nex_input() not implemented." and "tgt-vvp sorry: procedural continuous assignments are not yet fully supported. The RHS of this assignment will only be evaluated once, at the time the assignment statement is executed." I feel like im doing a lot wrong here but cant see it, are you able to help?

Comment: Here it is on edaplayground if that helps: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/y3F

Comment: Try taking the "assign" keyword out of the case block. You should really look at some examples of proper syntax.

Comment: Where would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the width when you declare an input or output as reg or wire. Add widths that match the ones used earlier. Or even better, combine them into one declaration (output reg [7:0] out;) instead of separate output and reg. Wire is the default so you don't need wire declarations for the inputs.